# how to connect multiple servers using perl?

Tags: perl, unix, vbscript

I have a server in which perl is installed. I was given a VB sript which connects different servers and fetch their respective  folder count.

My perl should be able to connect to all those different servers and copy the VB script in defined locations and execute the vb script.

What i like to know is, can we make perl execute the third part scripts in the server where perl is not installed or do we need to mount all those servers into the one single server where perl is installed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Please* put some effort into writing your questions. You are asking us to give you quality help for free but you cannot be bothered to present your question properly. Even though you are from India I am sure you can see your spelling mistakes as well as I can.

Comment: @ Borodin \I would accept that there are few spell mistakes, but how does that link to my country.

Comment: I am saying that it is no excuse that English may not be your first language

Comment: i will consider your suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`Net::SSH`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH) should do the job. The machines you are connecting to will need to be running an SSH server, but that will allow you to transfer files to them (scp/[sftp](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSFTP)) and get a remote shell so you can execute programs on them.